# Are there any examples of sending a video signal into an Android device via USB with the Android Open Accessory Development Kit (ADK)?

Tags: android, usb, adk, accessory

I'm researching the ability to use the Android Open Accessory Development Kit to send a video signal into an Android device via USB.  According to the documentation, it appears that it should be possible to connect a device and send a signal over USB that could be consumed in an Android app.  However, I haven't been able to find any examples that demonstrate sending a video signal.  Is it possible to perhaps connect a USB based webcam and communicate with it to get the video signal from it an display that inside an Android app?  I'm new to the ADK and have not interfaced with any hardware via Android yet.  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

The answer here refers you to the Android Open Accessory library. You can get the USB port to communicate with external devices ...but it uses a custom Android protocol

[Audio Over Micro USB - Android Open Accessory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650967/audio-over-micro-usb-android-open-accessory)