# Audio Over Micro USB - Android Open Accessory

Tags: android

OK. I am working on an independent project that is in the research stage. I have looked around the internet and have found nothing good about this topic. The websites I found are as respective in the programming communities as StackOverflow.

Using the Android Open Accessory library that has been included in Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread, is it yet possible to get audio from the device through the micro usb?

If not, is this something that would be specific to the Android OS and its software or does the issue reside in the manufacturer hardware?

Answer (score 4):

The Android Open Accessory library provides a basic communication channel with devices via USB. What you do with it is up to you.

(It doesn't have any inherent support for audio, and you can't route the system audio over it. But you could write code which outputs a custom audio channel from your app.)

Keep in mind that the Open Accessory library uses a custom protocol, so won't work with things such as a standard USB DAC.

(For that, you'd want to use the USB Host mode APIs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html. The same caveats about not being able to route the system audio still apply.)

Answer (score 2):

Android/Linux USB audio driver compliant with FiiO USB DAC E7:
"The FiiO E7 Headphone Amplifier is an USB DAC dedicated to high fidelity headphone.
It works out of the box with my Ubuntu 11.04. I just plug it when I need it and several seconds later it appears in my output sound devices list."

"Buried in this thread is another person who successfully used his Beresford Caiman USB DAC on an Android tablet using USB Host. It's pretty easy to get working, all you need is an Android device with CyanogenMod7 support and USB HOST enabled. You need a powered hub for it to work though."

USB Audio Driver for ALSA "usbaudio.o" is likely missing in the current stock kernel of Android 4.0.3.

"Usbaudio.o" is present in the modded kernel of the Nook tablet which allows FiiO USB DAC E7 & Nook to interoperate:

"Usbaudio.o" is likely not present in the 4.0 kernel and FiiO USB DAC E7 doesn’t interwork with Google Galaxy Nexus:

For the time being, Google is not aware of the USB DAC market, and the USB DAC manufacturers do not know the Android devices, likely the predominant computer systems in the (near) future.

Likely, Google architects are aware that computer systems should be compliant with standard computer interfaces like USB:

And, likely it's not the case with some Google program managers:
. USB Host feature not activated in Android 4.0.0
. no support of USB Audio in Android 4.0.3.

As "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.", please find the complete post with hyperlinks at:
http://androidforums.com/3805383-post48.html

Answer (score 2):

As the Android Develop website say（http://source.android.com/accessories/audio.html），the conditions to get audio from android device is complied with the A.O.A protocol and run in the accessory mode，Not all the android devices support this protocol,it's specify by some combination of products IDs,0x2D02 - audio/0x2D03 - audio + adb/0x2D04 - accessory + audio/0x2D05 - accessory + audio + adb are availble,for more information,see the link:http://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html, it may help you